# How can I get more amps from a voltage regulator?

Tags: amperage, lm317

I'm a noob that is just getting started.

I'm using an LM317T to generate 6V but I need a little more amperage.  Can I just double my LM317T and resistors configuration and put them in parallel?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhUjsF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ignore the resistor.

Comment: Can we see your circuit please? And, just to be sure: you know that V isn't the unit of amperage, right? You really want more amperage, not more voltage?

Comment: Yes.  I want to get 2 full Amps at 6V.  The LM317 says up to 1.5A.

Comment: This will probably work. Could you show us your circuit? We have an awesome on-site editor. Press 'edit' to edit your question, and then Ctrl-M to start the online editor.

Comment: [This](http://ourlibro.com/2012/04/08/how-to-boost-current-in-lm317-regulator-circuit/) is a solution common 20yrs ago, today it is solved with a DC/DC converter. Those are generally cheaper, smaller and more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TI's datasheet shows to ways to increase the current output of a 317. The first one is basically what you're suggesting:

[image]

Notice the 0.2 Ohm resistors at each output. These allow for differences in the reference voltage between the 317 chips.

The second one uses external transistors instead of paralleling 317's:

[image]

This concept can also be done with a single external transistor as shown [here](http://electronics-diy.com/electronic_schematic.php?id=675):

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what those Op-amps or transistors do, but I guess I know what I'm doing tonight!  Thanks for the pictures.