How can a transistor in Voltage Follower (Common Collector) mode withstand more than VBE volts across the base emitter junction?
Let me confess before beginning that I am not so professional or expert in this field. I am a self learned hobbyist who learns things from YouTube and applies them in the reality.
Having worked with a bare LM317 before, it heats up a lot and struggles whenever the load tries to draw more than an ampere current. I attached a heatsink to it and now it can provide somewhat more than 1.5 Amps but still its quite inadequate for me. I actually need a constant voltage regulated but current boosted power supply. Upon searching the internet, and I came upon this...

from this webpage
The circuit at the first glance looks very fascinating yet a bit confusing as well. The way the output is directly connected to the base. According to the article I provided above, these configuration of transistors have been named as pass transistors which is very much similar to the emitter follower or common collector method which only boosts current leaving the voltage gain to unity.
Now I am afraid that the base-emitter voltage of 2n3055 is only 7 volts. And lets suppose that the output voltage of LM317 is regulated at 12 volts without any load at the emitter side for this moment.
Upon connecting a load of lower resistance , the emitter junction that was open becomes forward biased through the load and having 12 volt in the base, it should fry the transistor. Even though I have seen many videos on youtube about the of the circuit, but could not verify the authenticity of it. So I am posting my query here in this forum to get my doubts clear.
So here my questions are....

So will the pass transistor burn up in the case when base voltage is more than 7?
If no, then could you please explain why not?

Thanks and Regards.

Nothing has changed for the LM317.  It will still get hot at 1.5A of current.  What current and voltage do you need?  You state 1.5A is inadequate, but have you checked the LM317 datasheet.  1.5A is what it is capable of.  Have you checked out switchers?

"...the base-emitter voltage of 2n3055 is only 7 volts"?!?

The 7V you refer to is the absolute maximum reverse voltage and that is a typical value for bipolar transistors.

For a better circuit, see the second circuit at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72849/how-can-i-get-more-amps-from-a-voltage-regulator This type is known as outboard current boost.

@StainlessSteelRat I just want to acquire most of the current while having the ability to change the voltage using a potentiometer at the adjust pin of LM317

Please clarify "current boosed" in "I actually need a constant voltage regulated but current boosted power supply." Can you just buy a suitable SMPS with the output voltage and current you need and it's job done?

@winny maybe that's the only way left

@CoderBittu There are some reasonably priced options to buy. But you are also a self learned hobbyist. I cannot think of a better project and motivation for learning. So you might consider both directions. One to solve an immediate problem. The other to continue your education. The circuit you show isn't all that good, partly because the output isn't brought into regulation by the regulator. It hangs off the end, close by but not directly within the regulation loop. So your output voltage will vary somewhat with the load (some 100s of millivolts.) What's the max current you want to support?

@periblepsis 10A i supposed. But i think buying a regulated charger whould be better than taking this risk.

@CoderBittu 10 A is enough that you must worry about dissipation. But not so much that it is scary. You can spread the dissipation out into two or three power BJTs using a little emitter degeneration, for example. But some learning and thought would be needed. A commercial unit is likely best just to get the job done if this isn't to be a learning project.

First, that circuit is technically incorrect. Notice how there is no feedback from the output of the transistor to the regulator. More on that later. Also, the traditional way to do this circuit with a PNP pass transistor. Not the NPN. But this still doesn't answer your questions.
There is no reason the transistor would burn out if its base is 7V. 7V with respect to what? The B-E voltage drop is fixed at 750mV for any non-zero current. What this means for this circuit is that the emitter "tracks" the base voltage with a small offset (750mV). The voltage regulation is taking place at the base NOT the output of the transistor.
In this circuit, the way it is drawn the transistor is going to take on about 100x the current the regulator is going to source (hfe x base current).
This is where the problem lies with using a single NPN - you can't just tie the emitter back to the output of the regulator to regain feedback (you would shout the transistor). This is why the "proper" way to do this circuit is to use a PNP resistor on the front of the regulator and a low-ohm resistor to "pass" the current. That way, when current flows through the resistor, the voltage drop across it eventually matches Vbe and puts the transistor into conduction carrying the heavy weight (google PNP lm312 regulator circuits so you see what I'm talking about. I'm not going to post the schematic here. Maybe one day.).
Also, the 10uF capacitor has got to be some sort of joke. This circuit is mostly flawed and would not use this topology. You would also need a diode, reverse-biased across the whole circuit (not shown) - if the source supply shuts off or gets disconnected, and your down stream circuitry has appreciable capacitance, you COULD burn out the transistor by exceeding the reverse Vbe limit. You could do much better with the same complexity. Or even better still, use a switcher and eliminate the heat problem all together.

A 2N3055. Now that's a name I haven't heard in a long time. I've put on my tie-dye pants specially to answer this.

So will the pass transistor burn up in the case when base voltage is more than 7?

No.

If no, then could you please explain why not?

The base-emitter junction of the 2N3055 is forward biased so will only have about 0.7 - 1 V across it.
The 7 V limit on the base-emitter junction is for reverse bias. Note in this datasheet it is specified as an emitter-base voltage \$V_{EB}\$ of 7 V. The second subscript letter is taken as the 0 V reference, here the base, so the emitter can be up to 7 V positive with respect to the base. In other words this means the base is limited to -7 V of reverse bias with respect to the emitter. In your circuit the base is forward biased so this is not a problem for you.
You will need a heat sink on the 2N3055.

And lets suppose at 12 volt

It should be fine at 12 V output, subject to checking the thermal dissipation on the 2N3055 (and the LM317, if you're pulling enough current).

So is that circuit in the article fake?

It should work. It has the disadvantage that the base-emitter voltage drop is not compensated for by the LM317 so the output voltage will fall slightly with increasing load.
In the other circuit in your quoted article, using a PNP pass transistor, the LM317 senses the output voltage so will provide a more stable output voltage. It does however require a higher input voltage to maintain regulation.
The answer linked to by Peter Smith provides, at figure 14, an example of using an NPN pass transistor whilst still maintaining regulation by the LM317.

And lets suppose at 12 volt, will it?

@CoderBittu Magic smoke.

So is that circuit in the article fake? @winny

@CoderBittu No, why would it? It's an emitter follower basically so your base voltage will be about 0.6 V higher than emitter at all times. Have you tried to simulate your circuit?


Now I am afraid that the base-emitter voltage of 2n3055 is only 7 volts.

You misread the spec here. It's the emitter-base voltage (VEBO), not the base-emitter voltage. For diodes, there's no max forward bias voltage. Because, what breaks down a diode is either a high reverse voltage or a high forward current (of course, if you apply high voltage across a diode a high current will flow but still, the current will kill the diode). So, if you apply more than 7V across emitter (+) and base (–) the base-emitter junction may die.

The pass transistor will work as an emitter follower i.e. thanks to the local feedback the voltage at the emitter (combined output) will be less than the 317's output by the base-emitter drop of the pass transistor. For the expected collector currents you can find the base current (hFE or β drops with increased current) and from here can find the expected base-emitter drop.
